# Select only unique rows based on the first two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Here is a snippet of the table I am working with:

[image: SAMPLE]

My goal is to only select one of these highlighted rows (doesn't matter which). They have duplicate approval, amount, and type columns but unique numbers in the "test" column. I would like to select all of these with the exception of one of the highlighted rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "[greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgreatest-n-per-group%5D+%5Bsql-server%5D&searchOn=3)" problem. If you really don't care which row you get, you can use `@@SPID`:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT APPROVAL, amount, type, test,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY APPROVAL, amount, type -- this defines grouping 
      ORDER BY @@SPID -- this says "I don't care what order"
    ) 
  FROM dbo.source_table
)
SELECT APPROVAL, amount, type, test
  FROM cte 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you care, you can add different criteria, e.g.

```
  ORDER BY test DESC -- for the biggest value of test
```

Or

```
  ORDER BY test -- for the smallest value of test
```

If you don't care which `test` you get, why does it even get returned?

Comment: Surely there must be a duplicate this can be closed with?

Comment: Thanks so much! The issue here is our software is duplicating transactions at times and both of those values in test leads to the correct amounts, but having both in there is creating erroneous data. Thanks again!

Comment: @DaleK Surely, but did you find one that fits perfectly? I looked for a minute, but far too often I get back "no, that didn't answer my question because <some reason my situation is different>." It's easier to just answer than try to solve the entire site's duplicate problem every time - the bigger problem is that it's really hard to find a good canonical answer (never mind create one) that satisfies enough of the duplicates that it ends up being less frictional. IMHO, anyway.